# Azure Application Gateway Redirection

Tags: azure, redirect, azure-application-gateway

I'm Trying to create the following process in Azure Application Gateway - 
when a user tries to access  he will need to redirect to

only the SSL works for me. 
I've tried to configure the redirection in the rule but seems that it's not responding.

what am I missing?

Thank you all :)

Comment: ok, MS saying it's not supported yet! :(

Answer (score 0):

You can go with Listener to Listener redirection in Application gateway.

Listener 1(80)  --> (Redirects to) Listener 2(443)  --> HTTP Setting --> Backend sever(Listens on port 443)

Here is the reference link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/tutorial-http-redirect-powershell#add-a-listener-and-redirection-rule